# Mongoose gives no response when updating object in Mongo

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a simple ExpressJS/Node backend that contains a MongoDB database for which I use mongoose to interact. I can add objects to the db based on the UserSchema:

```
const userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    email : {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        trim: true,
        unique: 1
    },
    password : {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        minlength: 5
    },
    name : {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        maxlength: 30
    },
    lastname : {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        maxlength: 30
    },
    cart : {
        type : Array,
        default: []
    },
    history : {
        type: Array,
        default: []
    },
    role : {
        type: Number,
        default : 0
    },
    token : {
        type: String
    }
});
```

From the express Server, I can register and add a new user to the DB and I know this works

Server.js

```
//========================================
//                  Register User
//========================================
app.post('/api/users/register', (req, res) => {
    //create new User
    const user = new User(req.body);

    //save user
    user.save((err, doc) => {
        if(err)
            return res.json({success: false, err});
        res.status(200).json({
            success : true,
            userdata: doc
        });
    });
})
```

In User.js

```
//========================================
//            SAVE in DB
//========================================
const User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

Now when I want to login, operation where I need to check the email and password match I encounter a problem when everything is fine and I want to add the JWT to the object all is good until it gets to the save method, there nothing happens and it doesn't respond anymore. It's like it goes in an infinite loop. I get error when something is wrong, but on the positive case, it disappears and sends no response, to either mongo, node, debug anything.

Server.js

```
app.post('/api/users/login', (req, res) => {

//find the email for the user
User.findOne({'email' : req.body.email} , (err, user) =>{
    if(!user)
        return res.json({loginSuccess : false, message : 'Authentication failed, email not found'});

    //check the password
    user.comparePassword(req.body.password, (error, isMatch) => {
        if(!isMatch)
            return res.json({loginSuccess : false, message : 'Wrong password'});

        //generate token
        user.generateToken((err, user) => {
            if(err)
                return res.status(400).send(err);
            
            //store token as a cookie
            res.cookie('w_auth', user.token).status(200).json({
                    loginSuccess : true
            })
        })
        
    })
})
})
```

User.js

```
  const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const SALT_I = 10;
require('dotenv').config();
    //========================================
//            User Login
//========================================
userSchema.methods.comparePassword = function (candidatePassword, cb) {
    bcrypt.compare(candidatePassword, this.password, function(error, isMatch){
        if(error)
            return cb(error);

        cb(null, isMatch);
    })
}

userSchema.methods.generateToken = function (cb) {
    var user = this;
    var token = jwt.sign(user._id.toHexString(),process.env.SECRET)

    user.token = token;
    user.markModified('anything');
    user.save(function(err,user){
        if(err) return cb(err);
        cb(null,user);
    })
}
```

I get no more feedback in node console, debug, Mongo or even Postmen(I can wait here for minutes ) after user.save(...). I know it gets the good user and everything but I don't really know where to get from here. Also in Mongo I see no field for the token, I initially add an object with no token, can this affect everything? Is there another procedure to update an existing object in the collection?
[image]

In case GitHub is needed to see the code: [Link](https://github.com/Bogdan-Blaj/Ecommerce-full-stack)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed it's really strange, couldn't really debug what's wrong with this 'save' method. As a workaround, however, this one seems to work fine:

```
userSchema.methods.generateToken = function (cb) {
    var user = this;
    var token = jwt.sign(user._id.toHexString(), "mystupidsecret");
    console.log("in generateToken");

    console.log(user);
    user.token = token;
    console.log(user.token);

    var email = user.email;

    //save token
    User.updateOne({ _id: user._id }, { $set: { token: token } }, function(err, user){
        if(err) {
            console.log(err);
            return cb(err);
        }
        cb(null, user);
        // this one is for debug only!
        User.findOne({'email' : email} , (err, user) =>{
            console.log("After update: ", user)
        });
    });
    console.log('done');
}
```

It yields the following:

```
After update:  { cart: [],
  history: [],
  role: 0,
  _id: 5f3e48f09c7edc3f1c24a860,
  email: 'abc233@wp.pl',
  password:
   '$2b$10$iDeeehLOzbQi3dawqW8Lg.HPOvcRBDIS/YD9D1EmqBOH9Be31WpX2',
  name: 'ABCDEFGH',
  lastname: 'Doeasdasdas',
  __v: 0,
  token:
   'eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.NWYzZTQ4ZjA5YzdlZGMzZjFjMjRhODYw.aH9tCMbIK9t3CReiQg3Azln9Ca8xS7W0xL3qCMOKniY' }
```

Comment: This fixes the problem, one thing to say, in my case, I can't return the user from the update one because I can't use it to store the cookie, a little weird, but everything is good. Thank you!